# Calling function via pointer in lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, foreach

I am having vector, that stores classes of type `Sensor`, which each have a member function `refresh()`. This vector is member of my class `LogManager`.

```
class Sensor
{
    public:
        void refresh();
}

class LogManager
{
    private:
        std::vector<Sensor*> sensors;

        void refresh_sensors()
        {
            // TODO: use foreach
            
            for (uint i=0; i<sensors.size(); i++)
            {
                sensors[i]->refresh();
            }

            for_each(sensors.begin(), sensors.end(), [sensors]( void* ) void* -> {refresh();} );
        }
}
```

What I want to do is to change the for loop into the `std::for_each()` implementation. What you see above is my first try.

How can I access the member function `Sensor::refresh()` with the `for_each()` function?
Using a standard for loop like also above, I'd just use the `->` operator.

Stretch goal is also to replace the `std::vector<Sensor*> sensors;` with a pointer: `std::vector<Sensor*>* sensors;` so that I do not have to work with copies. How would the implementation look in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm.

```
for_each(sensors.begin(), sensors.end(), []( Sensor * sensor ) void -> { sensor->refresh(); } );
```

I didn't try compiling it, so there might be a syntax problem. Things I changed:

1. You're not using the [sensors] section, so I emptied that.
2. If you're using void *, you're almost certainly doing something very un-C++-like. I changed it to the proper type.
3. You're not returning any value, so I changed the void * to void.

I don't actually use for_each. I personally think this code is far cleaner:

```
for (Sensor * sensor: sensors) {
    sensor->refresh();
}
```

I think that's SIGNIFICANTLY easier to read. So doing it using for_each is a good practice problem, but I wouldn't have written it that way. Which also means I might have gotten the code slightly wrong.

Comment: Thanks to you both, actually. I need to do some learning on lambdas, I suppose. I used the `for_each()` function, since if I change my vector to a pointer to a vector, I suppose it is cleaner to read. Helped alot, so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to capture anything in the lambda in `for_each`. Instead, each pointer in the vector should be passed as an argument:

```
std::for_each(sensors.begin(), sensors.end(), 
              [](Sensor* s) { s->refresh();});
```

You don't need to (and shouldn't) make the vector a pointer, unless you want to pass it around without making copies. Since it's a private data member, that's probably not a good idea, and you can use references to do that anyway.